# ¿Error en paginacion en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade

Estoy tratado de realizar una paginación hacia un **`SP (Stored Procedure)`**, pero estoy teniendo problemas que al dar clic, por ejemplo en la **pagina 2** me envía el **error**:

> 404 Not Found.

Les comparto  el código.

Este es el **controlador:**

```
public function search(){      
    $period='201909';
    $ids ='470803';
    $conection = \DB::connection('sqlsrvgenealogy');
    $page = Input::get('page');
    $pageSize = 10;
    $offset = ($page * $pageSize) - $pageSize;
    $datas = $conection->select('EXEC Sp_TreePerId ?,?', array($ids, $period));
    $data = array_slice($datas, $offset, $pageSize, true);
    $posts = new LengthAwarePaginator($data, $total = 50, $pageSize, $page);
    $posts->setPath('blog');
    \DB::disconnect('sqlsrvgenealogy');
    return view('genealogy')->withPosts($posts);
}
```

Les dejo la **vista:**

```
    @foreach ($posts as $result)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $result->Line }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->Level }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->associateid }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->associatename }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->Distributor_status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->mobile_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->alternative_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $result->country }}</td>
        </tr> 
    @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table> 
<?php echo $posts->render();  ?>
```

Y el **route:**

```
Route::get('/genealogy', 'Controller@search');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He logrado  resolver el problema por medio  de

```
    $posts->setPath(request('http://localhost/MyNikken/public/genealogy'));
```

Comment: mira por favor [answer]. Donde pusiste eso? donde estaba el problema???

Comment: Hola Emmanuel, me alegro que encontraras una solución, pero deberías añadir algo más de detalle a tu respuesta: ¿Qué es lo que hace `require` para que funcione? ¿al ser una dirección en localhost, seguirá funcionando si se sube a un servidor?